# Uploading a File to GAE Blobstore from URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I need to get a video from a URL, for example:

```
https://zencoder-temp-storage-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/o/20130722/5aacb76fc3fd47715c0329d1235dcccf/4fc612e92131e159abc761f7d54d86b5.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI456JQ76GBU7FECA&Signature=AGgZb1eMr105RXcoQFp8yFFTfFg%3D&Expires=1374614893
```

and then use Google App Engine to save it to the blobstore (or possibly Google Cloud Storage if the blobstore can't download straight from a URL) is there a simple way to do this?  I already have it set up so that I can get a user to upload a video but I am not sure about doing it this way.  Is the URLFetch Library what I'm looking for?

Would it be something like:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    #I'm just not sure what to do here, how I can get that 'file' from a URL
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
    blob_info = upload_files[0]

    video = Video(
        title = "some title",
        video_ref = blob_info.key())
    video.put()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you will need to use urlfetch then use the google cloud storage client library(https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open) to write the results. You need to consider that urlfetch response size is limited to 32mb so you need to split download into 32mb pieces and also there is a 60 seconds user request limit or 10 minute taskqueue limit or the use backends which doesn't have a timeout limit.

You could also directly upload to blobstore or cloudstorage (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Uploading_a_Blob) which is handled by special instances that is designed to handle these uploads.

Comment: What do you mean "directly upload" and what sort of special instance?

Comment: It seems like your sample code above is for the result of blobstore handler anyway. So this is something that you would use if you post to the form with action=blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload') where /upload is routed to UploadHandler. This has no timeout limits except the blobstore filesize limit.

Comment: Right, well I know pretty well how to get the user to upload a video, I just need to do it from a different URL

Comment: Then yeah the only way is download and write with cloud storage client or files api which I believe is deprecated. I hope the cloud storage client supports blobstore.

Comment: is there a way or a working example on how to use Google Cloud Storage with JAVA/JAVASCRIPT instead of always Python Python Python and another time Python? :-)